# WAMP Server 2 Error when Open

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have installed the WAMP server 2 in my Laptop and the Operating system using is Windows7. When I try to open PHP MyAdmin it always gives the following message in the browser.

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

So when I try to put the server online it gives this error message:

> wamp server could not execute menu item (internal Error) [Exception]
>   could not perform action: The service has not been started

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens like this?
I can't anymore open the PHP my admin or Localhost.

Comment: once uninstall and then install again

Comment: I did Uninstall and reinstall. But same thing

Comment: than check hardware / software requirement for wamp 2

Comment: @JibW - Try to run XAMPP  tool and start services  as an administrator.

Comment: wamp kinda sucks.. I did all my learning on a linux computer maybe you should too.

Answer (score 2):

The server offline has no relation to your problem.

Click on the icon in the system tray, and check that Apache and MySQL are on. You do this from

> Apache>Service>(check that start/resume service is disabled)
>
> MySQL>Service>(check that start/resume service is disabled)

If Apache is not on, click `start/resume service`. If it still doesn't come on, click on `Test port 80` This should tell you if port 80 is blocked (usually Skype blocks it. In that case, exit the program blocking port 80, start Apache and then you can resume the program that you terminated earlier)

If Apache is on, and the icon is still orange, it means MySQL is either (a) off or (b) running independently.

If MySQL is off, turn it on in the same way you would have done for Apache

If MySQL is separately installed, check the configuration from

> MySQL>my.ini

Look for something like

> The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
> [client]
> password       = root
> port       = 3306
> socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock

and put in the proper password and port for your mySQL instance

Answer (score 2):

my computer/manage/services

and stop sql reporting services

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message after installing WAMP. My problem was with Skype as mentioned by Pranav. Quitting Skype and 'Restarting All Services' and then clicking on 'Put Online' got WAMP working. Restarted Skype afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem following these steps:

`services.msc` and stop `Web Deployment Agent Service` which I recently installed. Also make it to start manually to not cause any problem in next start-ups.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur because You have installed Microsoft (SQL Server Management studio).

So,You need to stop SQL server reporting service and  all IIS services from mycomputer/services.

Then Restart all services of wampserver.

Comment: Could you please provide us more details on how to stop SQL server reporting service and all IIS services? or may be a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Apache and MySQL services are running (the tray icon should be green), if not, that's the place to start. Also check if you have multiple versions of them (from the previous install), perhaps the active one(s) is misconfigured.

Comment: The tray icon is Orange(WAMP server offline). When I try to turn it online the error message displays(The error in the above screen shot).

Comment: Check all the config files... but you said you reinstalled it. Try manually turning the services on from `services.msc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting following error

> Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The service has not been started

Solution 1:

Make sure none of following services is running on your system: IIS, Skype, Zone Alarm, NOD32, Eset, Internet Optimizer, Google Accelerator, any other database server, any other webserver..

If you using any of the above application close it and select “restart all services” from WAMP menu.

---

Solution 2:

Under Apache open the `httpd.conf` and change the lines

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

Make that 80 to 8080, save the file and select “restart all services”, it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager
The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used )
The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used )

FOR WAMP 32bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328

If you are using WampServer 2.4
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679
And select vcredist_x86.exe

FOR WAMP 64bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582

**Yes you need the x86 Package regardless**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523

If you are using WampServer 2.4
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679

And select vcredist_x64.exe

Then make sure you do not have another APache running. Lots of people come to WAMPServer after trying to install Apache, PHP and MySQL themselves. Make sure you uninstall any other attempts you may have made to `Do It Yourself`